# Why the menu of parent Activity is not shown in TabHost?

Tags: android, menu, android-activity, android-tabhost

I have Activity A and a TabHost in it. My TabHost has 2 tabs. The fist tab has Activity B and the second tab has Activity C.

[image]

Activity A has a menu. Activities B and C does not have any menu.
When I click on Activity A I can open its menu but when I click on one of tabs, the menu of A is not shown. It means that Activity B or C is activated and I do not have access to the menu of A.

How can I have access to the menu or other resources of A when it has this TabHost?

Comment: Just curious, but can't you replicate the menu from `A` in the two activities from the `TabHost`, `B` and `C`?

Comment: Make a Parent Activity which has a Menu creation code. Now extend this Activity in other Activity like A , B and C. Try this and let me know whether its what you needed or not..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code in your tabbed acivities:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if(getParent() != null) {
        return getParent().onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

so basically your tabbed activities would "redirect" options menu request to host.

Answer (score 0):

You can have menu of Acrivity A into Acitvity B...

for that you should declare object of activity A into Activity B.....like below...

```
public static ActivityA a = null;
```

and declare **onMenuItemSelected()** method in Activity B as here....

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
     return a.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);       
}
```